# Twitter API/Query to search in user profiles?

Tags: search, url, twitter, user-profile

Is there some way I can search in the profiles of users on Twitter?

e.g. User A has mentioned that he is "security, hacking geek" and his website is http://hackme.com

Now i want to search in 2 ways:

1. Search for "security" or "hacking" in user profiles and all users including A who have the word security in their profiles will be returned
2. search for http://hackme.com and all users with that as their website or in their profile will be returned

NOTE: I do not want the tweets with the above words to be returned, I want to search in user profiles!

Comment: this site appears to be able to search by "bio": http://www.locafollow.com/content/faqs.  not sure how they do it tho :(

Comment: issue is without a proper support from twitter, we will always have to do hacks

Answer (score 0):

Answering a bit of an old question here but I found it relevant to what I'm currently looking at.

As far as I can tell, you need to either use a directory, as suggested in the previous comment  or roll your own hack.  [PeopleBrowsr](http://www.peoplebrowsr.com/) seems to achieve part of the solution in that it enables you to query profile fields but it doesn't appear to include URL in that search.  It's very expensive though.

I'm personally using the workaround of using a combination of Google site search, combined with the URL as a term.  It's certainly not foolproof by a long shot but if couple with some clever validation, you may be able to strip out a lot of the noise and make use of the results.

i.e. **site:twitter.com link:microsoft.com** gives you @MSConnect

There are a lot of exceptions to this rule and sometimes it's better with or without the link: command.  For the time being though, it seems that if you're not willing to pay, the best solution is to come up with your own workaround and accept that there will be a lack of precision in the results.